# Segmentation fault using gcc on iMac

Tags: c

I am writing a function which takes the starting pointer of the linked list and appends a new node with the value provided. The list I pass may be empty as well.
But when I try to run the program, I get segmentation fault 11. Can anyone help me find out where I am going wrong?

```
void appendList(struct list* list, int value) {
struct list* ptr = list;
struct list* temp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
temp->val = value;
temp->next=NULL;
if (ptr==NULL) {
    ptr = temp;
    return;
}
while ((ptr->next)!=NULL) {
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
ptr->next = temp;
}
```

Calling as:

```
int main()
{
struct list* result;
result = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
appendList(result,4);
appendList(result,2);
appendList(result,5);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the `list` argument is `NULL`, the function doesn't change it. Make it return a pointer, `struct list *appendList(...`.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to call function and tracking your first node?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.....memory (fun stuff)...interestingly, your function has no bug, but the way you call it makes a difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first iteration, when you call the function, your function never treats the list is empty, since you have manually created `result` node in `main`. As a result, its `next` pointer need not and apparently is not `NULL` (since you never assigned it `NULL` in the `main`) and which is why you may be crashing.

So to fix this crash, use the following `main`--

```
int main()
{
struct list* result;
result = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
result->next=NULL;
result->val = 0;

appendList(result,4);
appendList(result,2);
appendList(result,5);

return 0;
}
```

You may consider  `Daniel Fischer`'s comment and return a pointer, which will be a different way of fixing this issue.

Comment: The contents of the `malloc`ed memory are indeterminate, so the `next` pointer might legitimately be a null pointer. (I get what you mean, but "is never" is a bit strong, "need not and apparently is not" could be an alternative.)